# maven-plugin-testing-harness session.getLocalRepository() returns null

Tags: unit-testing, maven-plugin

When using MojoRule, the localRepository in the session is null even though I'm passing it in in my test pom

**Test Pom**

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>myplugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>isolatedFeatureBranch</artifactId>
            <goals>
                <goal>SetRepositoryProperties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <localRepository>${localRepository}</localRepository>
                <branchName>feature/defaultInPomFile</branchName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**Mojo Class**

```
/**
 * Maven Project Access
 */
@Component
protected MavenProject project;

/**
 * Local Repository.
 */
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${localRepository}", readonly = true, required = true )
private ArtifactRepository localRepository;
```

**Test Code**

```
  @Rule public TestName name = new TestName();
  @Rule public MojoRule mojoRule = new MojoRule();
  @Rule public TestResources testResources = new TestResources(testProjects.getAbsolutePath(), workDir.getAbsolutePath());

  private MavenProject project;
  private MavenSession session;
  private SetRepositoryPropertiesMojo mojo;
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // setup with pom set BRANCHNAME  set in pom
    File pomDir = testResources.getBasedir("SetPropertiesTestsDefaultInPom");
    project = mojoRule.readMavenProject(pomDir);

    session = mojoRule.newMavenSession(project);

    // Generate Execution and Mojo for testing
    MojoExecution execution = mojoRule.newMojoExecution("SetRepositoryProperties");
    mojo = (SetRepositoryPropertiesMojo) mojoRule.lookupConfiguredMojo(session, execution);

  }
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at SetPropertiesFeatureBranchTests.setRemoteRepositoryHappyPath(SetPropertiesFeatureBranchTests.java:98)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to create a localRepository and then use the request to attach it to the session.  After which, we create the mojo and the class's localRepository variable contains the repo

**Test Code**

```
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // setup with pom set BRANCHNAME  set in pom
    File pomDir = testResources.getBasedir("SetPropertiesTestsDefaultInPom");
    project = mojoRule.readMavenProject(pomDir);

    // Generate session
    session = mojoRule.newMavenSession(project);

    // add localRepo - framework doesn't do this on its own
    ArtifactRepository localRepo = createLocalArtifactRepository();
    session.getRequest().setLocalRepository(localRepo);

    // Generate Execution and Mojo for testing
    MojoExecution execution = mojoRule.newMojoExecution("SetRepositoryProperties");
    mojo = (SetRepositoryPropertiesMojo) mojoRule.lookupConfiguredMojo(session, execution);

  }

 /**
   * Generate a local repository
   * @return local repository object
   */
  private ArtifactRepository createLocalArtifactRepository() {
    return new MavenArtifactRepository("local",
        localRepoDir.toURI().toString(),
        new DefaultRepositoryLayout(),
        new ArtifactRepositoryPolicy( true, ArtifactRepositoryPolicy.UPDATE_POLICY_ALWAYS, ArtifactRepositoryPolicy.CHECKSUM_POLICY_IGNORE ),
        new ArtifactRepositoryPolicy( true, ArtifactRepositoryPolicy.UPDATE_POLICY_ALWAYS, ArtifactRepositoryPolicy.CHECKSUM_POLICY_IGNORE )

    );
  }
```